# How to check if billing and shipping address are equal?

Tags: orders, magento-1, quote, shipping-address, billing

I'm trying to check if billing and shipping address are equal when creating invoice PDFs.

What I've tried so far was:

```
$order = $invoice->getOrder();
if( $order->getBillingAddress()->getData() != $order->getShippingAddress()->getData() )
```

or

```
$order = $invoice->getOrder();
if( $order->getShippingAddress()->getData('same_as_billing')!='1' )
```

but neither works. I was also trying to get the quote by using `$order->getQuote()` but that didn't work either.

Is there any way to check if billing and shipping address are equal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so here's my attempt following ProxiBlue's suggestion:

```
$excludeKeys = array('entity_id', 'customer_address_id', 'quote_address_id', 'region_id', 'customer_id', 'address_type');
$oBillingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress()->getData();
$oShippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData();
$oBillingAddressFiltered = array_diff_key($oBillingAddress, array_flip($excludeKeys));
$oShippingAddressFiltered = array_diff_key($oShippingAddress, array_flip($excludeKeys));

$addressDiff = array_diff($oBillingAddressFiltered, $oShippingAddressFiltered);

if( $addressDiff ) { // billing and shipping addresses are different
    // Print stuff
}
```

Basically I'm stripping out some keys by using an `$excludeKeys` array, so `array_diff` will be comparing only the relevant data. To strip out several keys without having to create a loop, I'm using `array_diff_key` in combination with `array_flip` to get rid of the unnecessary array keys.

Improvements and feedback welcome. :)

Comment: While this will work in almost all practical cases, it should be `array_diff_assoc` because array_diff only compares the values, so if you for example switch first name and last name, the addresses will still be treated as equal.

Answer (score 10):

Use array_diff.

```
$order = $invoice->getOrder();
$billing = $order->getBillingAddress()->getData();
$shipping = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData();

$diff = array_diff($billing,$shipping);
```

ref: https://www.php.net/array_diff

you may have to strip out some of the data of each array, before the diff. I am sure you can work it out ;)

Comment: While this will work in almost all practical cases, it should be `array_diff_assoc` because array_diff only compares the values, so if you for example switch first name and last name, the addresses will still be treated as equal

Answer (score 7):

Even though there is already an accepted answer, I'd like to share this solution I saw (similar) once in a 3rd party module:

```
function serializeAddress(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)  {  
        return serialize(
            array(
                 'firstname' => $address->getFirstname(),
                 'lastname'  => $address->getLastname(),
                 'street'    => $address->getStreet(),
                 'city'      => $address->getCity(),
                 'postcode'  => $address->getPostcode(),
                 //add the attributes you want to check for here for ex. company,...
            )
        );
}
```

Which was then called:

```
$shippingAddress = $invoice->getShippingAddress();

if (!$shippingAddress->getSameAsBilling()) {

     $shippingData = $this->serializeAddress($shippingAddress);
     $billingData = $this->serializeAddress($invoice->getBillingAddress());

     if (strcmp($shippingData, $billingData) != 0) {
        return false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the quote using

```
$order = $invoice->getOrder();
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order->getQuoteId());
```

Then you can get the shipping address from the quote and check if it is marked as being the same as the billing address:

```
if($quote->getShippingAddress()->getSameAsBilling()){
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Where is it being marked as the same? It seems like it is not working for me, because customer always has it marked the same even if default addresses are clearly different.

Answer (score 0):

had to compare addresses - one of them was just created (not saved). Perhaps it helps somebody:

based on @Alphawolf answer:

```
public function isDifferentAddresses(Mage_Customer_Model_Address $adr1, Mage_Customer_Model_Address $adr2, array $excludeKeys = array())
{
    if (!count($excludeKeys)) {
        $excludeKeys = array(
            'entity_id',
            'entity_type_id',
            'attribute_set_id',
            'is_active',
            'increment_id',
            'parent_id',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
            'customer_id',
            'customer_address_id',
            'quote_address_id',
            'region_id',
            'address_type',
            'is_default_billing',
            'is_default_shipping',
            'save_in_address_book'
        );
    }
    $excludeKeys = array_flip($excludeKeys);
    $adr1Filtered = array_diff_key($adr1->getData(), $excludeKeys);
    $adr2Filtered = array_diff_key($adr2->getData(), $excludeKeys);
    $diff = array_diff_assoc($adr1Filtered, $adr2Filtered); 
    return !empty($diff);
}
```

**EDIT 20 01 2016**

im using the following method since i posted the version above and it works for me -- thought it may help somebody:

```
/**
 * returns if address 1 is different to address 2
 *
 * @param Mage_Customer_Model_Address $adr1
 * @param Mage_Customer_Model_Address $adr2
 * @param array                       $excludeKeys
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isDifferentAddresses(Mage_Customer_Model_Address $adr1,
    Mage_Customer_Model_Address $adr2, array $excludeKeys = array()
) {
    if (!count($excludeKeys)) {
        $excludeKeys = array(
            'prefix',
            'suffix',
            //'region',
            //'region_id',
            'entity_id',
            'vat_id',
            'entity_type_id',
            'attribute_set_id',
            'is_active',
            'increment_id',
            'parent_id',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
            'customer_id',
            'customer_address_id',
            'quote_address_id',
            'address_type',
            'is_default_billing',
            'is_default_shipping',
            'save_in_address_book'
        );
    }
    $excludeKeys = array_flip($excludeKeys);
    $adr1Filtered = array_diff_key($adr1->getData(), $excludeKeys);
    $adr2Filtered = array_diff_key($adr2->getData(), $excludeKeys);
    $diff = array_diff_assoc($adr1Filtered, $adr2Filtered);
    return !empty($diff);
}
```