# How to check billing and shipping address are same

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I am using magento 2.0.7 and i want to know how the checkout page works and how to display the shipping and billing address. Where is checking the shipping and billing address are same or not for logged in users

Comment: Did you try https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11085/how-to-check-if-billing-and-shipping-address-are-equal ?